# Adding the dots at the end of Textview (...) , dots not showing

Tags: android, textview

Whenever a text (That I set programmatically from an Activity) is longer than *n* charachters, I want to cut off and limit the texts length and add 3 dots at the end of the `textview`. Text is initially set to empty (just "") in `xml`, and is set from activity later.

This is how I tried:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

This is how it ends up looking with a random text, and I set the maxlength to 10 charachters:

[image]

I was expecting it to look like `jrkfkgkglg...` because the text is `jrkfkgkglggfgirng`, but the dots are not added at the end. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work, your width must be `match_parent` or have a any other size defined instead of being `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling your edit text to be maximum 10 chars in length, in your screenshot, you have a string with that length so if you will try to add anything to that string it won't get added.

You can remove the `android:maxLength="10"` limit and check your text from your code programmatically, something like this:

```
if (yourText.length() > 10) {
    yourText = yourText.substring(0, 9); //get the first 10 chars
    textView.setText(yourText + "..."); //display 
} else {
    textView.setText(original string < 10chars);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to remove the attribute

> android:maxLines="1"

and add the new attribute

> android:singleLine="true"

and in addition make your textview width match_parent.
It will work properly when you will add this then you don't need to use anything else.